# What is wrong with the way the view model is being injected into the Vue control in this example?

Tags: vue.js, model, components

The following example gives the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'count1')".

File: button.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Button Counter</title>
    <script src="/js2/vue-global-min-3.3.4.js"></script>
    <script src="button.js"></script>

    <script>
        const vm = Vue.reactive
        (
            {
                count1: { count: 0 },
                count2: { count: 0 },
                count3: { count: 0 }
            }
        );

        initButton();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <button-counter id="b1" :count="vm.count1"></button-counter>
        <button-counter id="b2" :count="vm.count2"></button-counter>
        <button-counter id="b3" :count="vm.count3"></button-counter>
        <div id="r1">{{ vm.count1.count }}</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

File: button.js

```
var initButton = function ()
 {
    const ButtonCounter =
    {
        props: ['count'],
        emits: ['update:count'],
        template: `
            <button @click="incrementCount">
                You clicked me {{ count }} times.
            </button>
        `,
        setup (props)
        {
            const incrementCount = () =>
            {
                this.$emit ('update:count', { ...props.count, count: props.count + 1 });
            };

            return { incrementCount };
        },
    };

    function registerTag ()
    {
        const app = Vue.createApp ({});
        app.component ('button-counter', ButtonCounter);
        app.mount ('#app');
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', registerTag);
};
```

I was expecting to see three buttons and the div text.  I got the error mentioned above.  I checked the expression "vm.count1.count" and it is a Vue reference with the value 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vm` is defined in the global scope, but Vue needs it declared in the corresponding component, which in your case is the root component. A quick fix is to return it from a setup function:

```
    function registerTag ()
    {
        const app = Vue.createApp ({
          setup(){         // <------  add a setup() function which returns vm
            return {
              vm
            }
          }
        });
        app.component ('button-counter', ButtonCounter);
        app.mount ('#app');
    }
```

Or move the declaration into the setup block completely, which would get you closer to a typical Vue setup, as you can explore in the [Vue 3 sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-glziy?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: Thanks.  That's a subtle, but important, point.